# setting html select with jquery val() with its innerhtml

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the selected attribute on a select pull down with jquery val(). I only have the caption (aka innerhtml) of the element I want the selected, but not the value.
For example:

A pulldown of states. I want the "New york" option to be selected. I want to write a jquery statement which does

```
$("#pull-down").val([get value of the option tag which has "New York" as its innerhtml])
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` method.

```
$("#pull-down").val(function(){
    return $('#selectElement option').filter(function(){
                return $(this).text() === 'New York';
           }).val();
});
```

In case that `#pull-down` is a select element and the option element that contains `New York` is child element of it, you can use `prop` method.

```
$('#pull-down option').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text() === 'New York';
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the value of `#pull-down` to the value of the `<option>` that contains "New York". Case sensitive.

```
$("#pull-down").val($("option:contains('New York')").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/RkBd2/

```
<select name="states">
    <option></option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
</select>

$('select[name="states"]').val('TX');
```

Will result in the drop down showing Texas.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're trying to select a select option with a given value, (in this case, somevalue), do this:

```
 $('#pull-down option[value="somevalue"]').select();
```

Comment: That doesn't select the proper value in the drop-down. It doesn't select anything as far as I can see when testing in jsfiddle.

Comment: Too true.  I forgot some quotes.  Now she should run.